# swift search Bar and navigation bar will be hidden after starting

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, searchbar

in my swift 2 app i have a table view with a search bar:

[image]

But if tap on the search bar, my navigation bar and the search bar will be hidden.

[image]

This is my code which is in the viewDidLoad

```
        self.resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
            self.MyTable.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

            return controller
        })()
```

At the beginning i also get this message:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is
>   deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior
>   ()

My Question is, where is my mistake? :/

Comment: Have you tried making a global (and strong) object for `UISearchController`?

Comment: what do you mead with making a global and strong object? i have this line at the beginning: `var resultSearchController = UISearchController()`

Answer (score 1):

from [this](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) tutorial you can use this code to solve the problem.

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
searchController!.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

// This makes the view area include the nav bar even though it is opaque.
// Adjust the view placement down.
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.Top
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your code with the below if you want to make it worked perfectly:

```
        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationItem.searchController = self.resultSearchController
        } else {
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
        }
```